# Plotting a graph

Tags: plotting, integral-equations

Could anyone help me with plotting the following graph?

```
Integrate (-Inf, Inf) (exp(-i*x*t))/((4*pi)((x-1)^2 +25)(exp(-100x) +1))
```

It's not a code obviously, but I don't need a code, it's simple enough. Mathematica times out when I try to pot this. Is there a way around it? Could anyone try and plot it?

Further info: Plot for t = 0 to 100. And the integration is over x.

Comment: If you have tried already, why not posting the actual code ?

Comment: Is this a double integral? x from - infinity to + infinity and t from 0 to 100?

Comment: @b.gatessucks Because I wrote it on another computer.. is it really a code? I just wrote this equation and wrote integrate and wrote the intervals -Inf to Inf, but I couldnt put a range for t(dont know how to), so I only put 0,1,2,3.. manually for t.

Comment: @Vaggelis_Z no it's not a double integral. the integral over x would give a number. I just need that number for different t's. And i need to plot only the real part of the graph.

Comment: Mathematica already never finishes an evaluation for a single given value of t. You probably should use `NIntegrate` instead of `Integrate`. Note that the result is complex, and cannot be plotted as is. You need `Abs` or `Re`, depending on your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your data/function generates complex value. So I plotted the Re part only. It was hard to read your code, so check that I translated it ok to Mathematica.

```
f[t_?NumericQ] := 
 Quiet@NIntegrate[ 
   Exp[-I*x*t]/((4*Pi) ((x - 1)^2 + 25) (Exp[-100 x] + 1)) , {x, -Infinity,Infinity}];
data = Table[{t, f[t]}, {t, 0, 100, .5}];
ListLinePlot[Re@data, Frame -> True,FrameLabel -> {{"f(t)", None}, 
  {t, "Plot of function"}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

To change `PlotRange`, see options. If you do not give `PlotRange`, Mathematica decides on one. So do like this:

```
ListLinePlot[Re@data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"f(t)", None}, {t, "Plot of function"}}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-10^-5, 10^-5}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Or use `All`

```
ListLinePlot[Re@data, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{"f(t)", None}, {t, "Plot of function"}}, 
 PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: Thank you. could you say how I could see this for a larger range of f(t)?

Comment: @user10366, just play with the PlotRange. Either use `All`, or give specific plot range. Will add small example. See help for syntax if not sure how. Notice, I used Frame->True, so plot range syntax is a little different.